# Show tooltip(in span) always top in table

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a table and I made a tooltip with CSS

its shows up when u hover mouse on `<td>`

*here's my jsfiddle* : `www.jsfiddle.net/4qzurb5w/`

How can I make this tooltip always shows up everything in table?

Comment: What do you mean by `How can I make this tooltip always shows up everything in table?`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Justcode tooltip appears on behind the bottom td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of this block, it is conflicting:

```
.green:hover,
.blue:hover,
.red:hover,
.yellow:hover,
.black:hover {
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```

It should work then.

I moved your opacity style to `.tooltip .tooltiptext`, see stack snippet.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  opacity: 0.8; /* <-- I added your opacity here */
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.div table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  background: #eaebec;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}

.div table caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.div td {
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #fafafa;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #fafafa);
}

.red {
  background: #940000 !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.blue {
  background: #1C2CFA !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.black {
  background: #000000 !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.yellow {
  background: #009999 !important;
  color: Green !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.white {
  background: #fafafa !important;
  color: #666 !important;
}

.grey {
  background: #808080 !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.ariza {
  background: #990000 !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.green {
  background: #00941C !important;
  color: White !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
}

.green:hover,
.blue:hover,
.red:hover,
.yellow:hover,
.black:hover {
  /* opacity: 0.8; get rid of this */
}

.green a,
.blue a,
.red a,
.yellow a,
.black a {
  display: block;
  color: White;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.yazitd {
  width: 70px !important;
}

.sagtd {
  width: 540px !important;
}

.tarihtd {
  width: 160px !important;
}

.style3 {
  width: 90px;
}

.style4 {
  height: 19px;
}

.style5 {
  width: 40px;
}

.style6 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 23px;
}

.style7 {
  height: 23px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; min-width: 50px !important; font-weight: bold;">KAT 1 </td>



      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="red tooltip">Daire No:1
                <div><span class="tooltiptext">ALEX DE SOUZA<br>HASAN ALİ KALDIRIM<br>ALPER POTUK<br>RIDVAN DİLMEN<br></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:2
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="red tooltip">Daire No:3
                <div><span class="tooltiptext">ALİ KOÇ<br></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:4
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>



    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; min-width: 50px !important; font-weight: bold;">KAT 2 </td>



      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip" style="font-weight: 400;">Daire No:5
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:6
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:7
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:8
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>



    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; min-width: 50px !important; font-weight: bold;">KAT 3 </td>



      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:9
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:10
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:11
              <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: top;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="green tooltip">Daire No:12
                <div><span class="tooltiptext"></span></div>
              </td>
            </tr>






          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>



    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```